# Text file to XML file convert

Tags: c#, xml

I going to convert text file to XML. I use the following code. But it generate error in line 12. Can anyone correct the code. Error is in this line.

> writer.WriteString(lines[0].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]); ------ "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("ex3.txt");
    char[] ca = new char[] { '\n' };
    using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("ex3.xml", null))
    {
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Header");
        writer.WriteStartElement("H1");
        writer.WriteString(lines[0].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("H2");
        writer.WriteString(lines[1].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Details");
        for (int i = 2; i < lines.Length - 2; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("D" + (i - 1).ToString());
            writer.WriteString(lines[i].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Footer");
        writer.WriteStartElement("F1");
        writer.WriteString(lines[lines.Length - 2].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("F2");
        writer.WriteString(lines[lines.Length - 1].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lines that read

```
writer.WriteString(lines[0].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]);
```

Simply remove the .Split(ca, 2)[1].
so...

```
writer.WriteString(lines[0].TrimEnd());
```

Answer (score 0):

The method File.ReadAllLines gives you an array which contains all lines in each entry.

Here you make a split on "\n" in the first line. But the line cannot contain a "\n" anymore because the ReadAllLines has already splitted the text in lines.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Can you provide the necessary code so i can understand it clearly

Answer (score 0):

It means one of the arrays in that line isn't as big as you think it is - either the file `ex3.txt` is empty, or (far more likely) the result of splitting a single line of text (the result of a call to `File.ReadAllLines()` (`lines[0]`) on a newline character does not have a second line - which is clearly impossible.

In response to your comment:

Let's break down the line that's causing your error:

```
writer.WriteString(lines[0].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]);
```

`writer.WriteString();` does the writing...but what does it write?

`lines[0]` is the first line of the file `ex3.txt`.

`lines[0].TrimEnd()` is the first line of the file `ex3.txt` with any whitespace at the end removed.

`lines[0].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)` will return an array of at most 2 elements, consisting of the first line of the file `ex3.txt` with any whitespace at the end, split on the elements of the array `ca`, which consists of a newline.  As the string contains one line, it will never have more than 1 element.

`lines[0].TrimEnd().Split(ca, 2)[1]` is therefore going to cause an exception every time, because you try and access the second element of an array that will never have more than one element.

It is impossible to post code that will solve your problem without more details of the problem you're trying to solve, and the exact format of the input file.

Comment: Can you provide the correct answer, so i can understand clearly

Comment: Text file contain data as fallows:

aaaaaaaa


bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
dddddddd